# Find $p$ and $q$ such that the maximum and minimum values of $5 +6\cos\theta + 2 \cos2\theta$ satisfy $x^2-p x+q=2$

Tags: real-analysis

> If the maximum and minimum values of $5 +6\cos\theta + 2 \cos2\theta$ satisfy $x^2-px + q = 2$, then what are $p$ and $q$?

My thinking that, maximum valus  of $\cos\theta$ is $1$ and minimum is $-1$. Now I can claim that the maximum of $5+6\cos\theta + 2 \cos2\theta)$ is $13$ and the minimum value is $9$

So $p = 13$ and $q=9$.

Is it correct or not?

Any hints/solution?

Thank u

Comment: Where did you get your numbers?  If we take $\theta = \pi$ then your expression is $5-6+2=1$ so $9$ certainly isn't the minimum.

Comment: Min seems like 3/4.

Comment: yaa,,,that  was my mistake @lulu

Comment: Use $ \cos(2 \theta) =2 \cos^2 \theta -1$ and complete the square ... Now have a little think about what the maximum & minimum values will be.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit...what  is the value of p and q ?

Comment: $p$ will be the sum of the maximum & minimum. $q-2$ will be their product.

Comment: q- 2  will be thier product  ??im not getting  @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: $x^2-px + q = 2$ ... rearrange to $\cdots =0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum value is wrong. Let $f(t)=5+6t+2(2t^{2}-1)$. [Recall that $\cos (2x)=2\cos^{2}x-1$]. Therefore, $f'(t)=6+8t=0$ when $t=-3/4$ which is a possible value for $\cos x$. So the minimum value is $5+6(-3/4)+2(9/8-1)=3/4$. The quadratic with leading coefficient $1$ and roots $3/4$ and $13$ is given by $(x-\frac 3 4 ) (x-13)=0$. Comparing coefficienrs we get $p=\frac {55} 4$ adn $q=\frac {47} 4$

Comment: then what is the  value of p and q ?

Comment: @Messififa I have edited my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir, will we not put  (x-3/4)(x-13) =2